# How to fix this MySQL syntax error

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

This is my source code.

```
    private void btnLoadActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {     
    public void saveOrder(JTable jTable2, JDateChooser jd) {
    if (jTable2.getRowCount() > 0) {

        for (int i = 0; i < jTable2.getRowCount(); i++) {
            int lot_id = Integer.parseInt(jTable2.getValueAt(i, 0).toString());
            String lot_date = jTable2.getValueAt(i, 1).toString();
            String lot_type = jTable2.getValueAt(i, 2).toString();
            int draw = Integer.parseInt(jTable2.getValueAt(i, 4).toString());
            int f_order = Integer.parseInt(jTable2.getValueAt(i, 5).toString());
            int qty = Integer.parseInt(jTable2.getValueAt(i, 6).toString());
            double cost = Double.parseDouble(jTable2.getValueAt(i, 7).toString());
            double profit = Double.parseDouble(jTable2.getValueAt(i, 8).toString());


                    try {
                    boolean b = JDBC.putData("insert into order(lot_date, inst_id, qty, total, ptotal) values('"+lot_date+"', '"+lot_id+"', '"+qty+"', '"+cost+"', '"+profit+"' )");

                    if (b) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "invoice saved one");

                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }


    } else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Enter Item to Invoice", "Error",                   JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
}}
```

This is my JDBC class.

```
package Modle;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;


  public class JDBC {
  static Connection con;
  static boolean b;
  public static void setCon() {
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/lottery", "root", "");
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static Connection getCon() throws Exception{
    if (con==null) {
        setCon();
    } 
        return con;
  }

public static boolean putData(String sql){
    try {
        PreparedStatement state = getCon().prepareStatement(sql);
        state.executeUpdate();
        b=true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    b=false;
    }
    return b;
   }

}
```

when I press this button I have a syntax error exception.

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'order(lot_date, inst_id, qty, total, ptotal) values('2014-11-14', '4', '5', '100' at line 1
```

This is my order table.

[image: Order table]

At this movement I didn't add values to lot_id and draw fields. Please help me. 

![enter image description here][2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`order` is a reserved word in SQL, so if you want to use it as a table name you need to protect it with forward quotes:

```
boolean b = JDBC.putData("insert into `order` (lot_date, inst_id, qty, total, ptotal) values ('"+lot_date+"', '"+lot_id+"', '"+qty+"', '"+cost+"', '"+profit+"' )");
```

Answer (score 1):

[Mureinik's answer is correct](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26794125/1031945).

This has nothing to do with error but when you are already using `PreparedStatement` then use place holders(`?`) for setting values.
This prevents [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attack.

### Update

[Why do I use PreparedStatement?](http://blog.jooq.org/2013/08/12/10-more-common-mistakes-java-developers-make-when-writing-sql/)

For simple reasons:

> - You can omit syntax errors originating from bad string concatenation when inlining bind values.
> - You can omit SQL injection vulnerabilities from bad string concatenation when inlining bind values.
> - You can avoid edge-cases when inlining more “sophisticated” data types, such as TIMESTAMP, binary data, and others.
> - You can keep open PreparedStatements around for a while, reusing them with new bind values instead of closing them immediately (useful in Postgres, for instance).
> - You can make use of adaptive cursor sharing (Oracle-speak) in more sophisticated databases. This helps prevent hard-parsing SQL statements for every new set of bind values.

### See also

- [Preventing_SQL_Injection_in_Java](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Preventing_SQL_Injection_in_Java)
- [PreparedStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)
- [why-use-preparedstatement-in-java-jdbc?](http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2012/03/why-use-preparedstatement-in-java-jdbc.html)

Comment: I thought adding prepared statements in every insert code will slow the system.. Is it not? Thanks for your information. Nobody told me that.